# How do I setup .git with bitbucket to automatically update live Magento site when pushes are made?

Tags: php, git, magento, bitbucket

I have a number of currently live Magento websites which I'm looking to take copies of and integrate Git with Bitbucket into. I want to do this to make future changes traceable with the ability to be able to roll back should anything go wrong!

Here's how I understand it should work:

1. Create bitbucket repository
2. Install .git on both local machines and live server
3. Download copies of live site files and database
4. Clone repo to local machine
5. Import all files into cloned repo
6. Push back up to repo
7. Setup php file on live site to `git pull` from repo
8. Link php file as a *Service Hook* in bitbucket

What I need to know is if I'm missing anything from the above steps and how you would migrate a currently live Magento site to your local machine and get it all working again.

Comment: You shouldn't have control version on your production! Use stage for it.

Comment: Production is the most important place to have version control, but yes you should be doing this in staging

Comment: Thanks for the comments, can either of you help confirm the correct process and if possible detail it further for me?

Comment: Bit bucket would need a plugin for post commit hooks, which you would set up only on your master branch. It could perform a secure request to a script on your web server or master web server which would "pull" your mastered branch and refresh your cache

Answer (score 0):

First of all here is my suggestion for your Git architecture:

Create two branch in your local and two branch in Bitbucket (Let's name them *Dev* and *Master*). It is very important to have a dedicated branch (*Master*) in Bitbucket that your server securely pulls from it; in this way you try to prevent messing things up.

In your local always *push* from your *Dev* branch and merge your *Master* branch after it. And in your server *pull* only from *Master* branch in Bitbucket.

For making a copy of your Magento:
First dump your DB and import it in your local DB. Then copy all the files from *public_html* folder in your server to your local. You might need to change a few things in your DB (in *core_config_data* table) and your *.htaccess* file ([Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server#update_1)).

Take the DB user credentials from: *app/etc/local.xml* file and create this user in your local DB. If you are lucky enough it should do the job if not search for it, you'll find hundreds of dedicated questions/answers all over the Internet.

Apart from these, for automatic updates you should look for CI (continuous integration) tools like Jenkins. Have a look at these links ([1](https://github.com/EcomDev/MageCI), [2](http://www.slideshare.net/meetmagentoes/magento-and-continuous-integration)).